# Selection of multiple html elements with the help of document.getSelection()

Tags: javascript, range, selection, rich-text-editor, multipleselection

How to iterate through the multiple selected html elements.

```
const selection = window.getSelection();
const selectedElements = selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents().querySelectorAll("*");
```

This gives all the elements, but I want only selected elements.

Comment: Surely, once you've cloned, the elements in the clone *won't be selected*?

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll("*")` retrieves all elements within the cloned range to filter this down to only the elements you want:

```
const selection = window.getSelection();
if (!selection.rangeCount) return;

const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
const clonedSelection = range.cloneContents();

// iterate through all elements
const selectedElements = [];
clonedSelection.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(el => {
    // apply your condition here.
    // example: check if the element's text is part of the selection
    if (range.toString().includes(el.textContent)) {
        selectedElements.push(el);
    }
});
```

Comment: It gives all the elements, i only want selected elements